# Malloc breaks when it oughtn't

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, struct, malloc

I've looked all over google and can't seem to comprehend why malloc is failing in my code. I have included the parts of the code I think are useful to understand the problem.

The strange part is that I used malloc 5 lines above in the exact same way, and it succeeds every time for the first one, but consistently fails for the second one. As I've gone through gdb, the pointer for parent->left_tree is 0x0 before it is malloc-ed, and it works fine, and then when it comes to parent->right_tree, it fails every time with the given cryptic error message. I've tried experimenting with different values inside the malloc, such as malloc(64) and malloc(10000), and the results are identical.

Here is the function of the code where malloc fails:

```
int
prefix_input( expr_tree_T parent )
{

    char *token = get_next_token();
    int int_value;
    double dub_value;
    int type = node_type(token);

    if (type == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: '%s' is invalid input.\n", token);
        exit(2);
    }

    parent->type = type;

    if (type == OPERATOR )
    {
        parent->value.operator = token[0];
        parent->left_subtree = malloc(sizeof(expr_tree_T));
        mem_check(parent->left_subtree, "left subtree");

        prefix_input( parent->left_subtree );

        parent->right_subtree = malloc(sizeof(expr_tree_T)); //<-- ***Right here***
        mem_check(parent->right_subtree, "right subtree");

        prefix_input( parent->right_subtree );
    }
    else if (type == INTEGER)
    {
        sscanf( token, "%d", &int_value );
        parent->value.int_value = int_value;
        parent->left_subtree = NULL;
        parent->right_subtree = NULL;
    }
    else if (type == DOUBLE)
    {
        sscanf( token, "%lf", &dub_value );
        parent->value.double_value = dub_value;
        parent->left_subtree = NULL;
        parent->right_subtree = NULL;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the code for the struct which is having the memory allocated to:

```
typedef struct expr_tree_node 
{ 

    struct expr_tree_node *left_subtree; 
    struct expr_tree_node *right_subtree;   

    int type; 

    union 
    {         
        char operator; 
        int int_value; 
        double double_value; 
    } value; 

} * expr_tree_T;
```

This is all my included header files:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

This is how the code is compiled:

```
gcc -Wall -std=c99 -D_POSIX_SOURCE A12P2.c -o a12p2 -g
```

This is a sample from debugging with GDB. I can observe that the pointer for parent->right_subtree is at 0, which as I've researched is the safest thing to use malloc on in general.

```
prefix_input (parent=0x804c008) at A12P2.c:171
171         parent->right_subtree = malloc(sizeof(expr_tree_T));
(gdb) print parent->left_subtree 
$7 = (struct expr_tree_node *) 0x804c160
(gdb) print parent->right_subtree 
$8 = (struct expr_tree_node *) 0x0
(gdb) s
a12p2: malloc.c:2369: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)-
>bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size
== 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct 
malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 
1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0xb7fdd424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
```

Comment: Something in your program is corrupting the heap. Use valgrind to help find it.

Comment: How are you calling `prefix_input()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of error indicates that your application has corrupted data structures used by `malloc()`. This usually happens because you have written outside an allocated block of memory, or have written to memory that has been freed.

In this case, it appears that you're not allocating enough memory for your structures:

```
parent->left_subtree = malloc(sizeof(expr_tree_T));
```

Given the prototype of this function, it looks as though `expr_tree_T` is a typedef for a pointer to a structure, not the structure itself. If this is indeed the case, then `sizeof(expr_tree_T)` ends up being the size of that pointer, not of the structure, so you're allocating much less memory than is actually needed!

I'd strongly recommend that you change the definition of this type to make it a name for the structure (so the function will now accept a `expr_tree_T *` as an argument). If you find the stars obnoxious, typedef the pointer to something like `expr_tree_ref` and use that as appropriate. In your header file, this might look something like:

```
typedef struct expr_tree {
    ....
} expr_tree_T, *expr_tree_ref;
```

Failing that, you will need to specifically reference the structure in your `sizeof()` expression:

```
malloc(sizeof(struct what_an_expr_tree_T_points_to))
```

which is (even once you use the real name, whatever it is) a lot messier than `sizeof(expr_tree_T)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I changed this and restructured some parts of the program and it's working fine. I guess I just need to brush up on my understanding of pointers and the like. When you said at the beginning, that my application probably corrupted data structures used by malloc(), what do you mean? Are you suggesting that my program just so happened to access some of the memory that malloc was trying to use for it's own purposes? Was this by chance, and could the program have accidentally accessed memory from other programs working inside of mine?

Comment: The memory allocator keeps "bookkeeping" data in the memory surrounding blocks it allocates. Writing beyond the end of an allocated block, or before the beginning, can corrupt this data. System memory protection prevents you from accessing memory from other programs, though - the worst you can generally do is mess yourself up.